# Which domain should I create my Service accounts in when deploying an Extranet on a Sharepoint WFE in the DMZ?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to install sharepoint on a server in the DMZ. Which domain (local or public (DMZ)) do I create the Service accounts in? Thanks

Comment: What is the farm topology (where do the servers physically reside)? What sort of domain trust is there?  Where is the SQL Server?

Comment: @shufler SQL2008 server(1) in local domain and Sahrepoint 2010 server(1) in public domain. The domain trust is two way. All the servers are virtual.

Comment: If the trust is two-way, it doesn't technically matter as a service account in either domain can be authenticated and authorized on machines in both domains. So the question to you is, Where do you want them to live?

Comment: @shufler I have them setup in the public domain AD. I am not really concerned about where they reside but am concerned on whether this would have any implications in the near future.

Comment: @shufler For example while trying to sync all user profiles from the local domain using a public\spfarm account will conflict. How would I overcome this?

Comment: I have a standalone server(WFE) in the DMZ and my Application Server and DB are on the internal network (LAN). My service accounts are created on the local internal domain (LAN). If trust has been setup betwen the standalone and the local internal domain, will I be able to use the service accounts created in local domain for installing SharePoint in the standalone server(WFE). Please let me know thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up creating all the accounts in the Public Domain and did not have any issues. 
Thanks again for all the posts.